# AWS EMR - how to get driver and worker node IP via CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I can get the master node IP with this:

```
aws emr describe-cluster  --output text  --cluster-id  $(aws emr list-clusters  --active --query 'Clusters[?Name==`ClusterName`].Id' --output text) --query Cluster.MasterPublicDnsName
```

However, I need the driver & the worker node IPs -- how do I get them?

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin no errors, it just gets the master node IP, I'd like to get the driver & worker node IPs